# Embedding Google Group Members

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-groups

I have a bootstrap site that I would like to embed a google group member list in. I just need people to be able to view the list, so that they can see the contact info for all of the members of the group. I haven't found anything to try, so I haven't really tried anything. I don't know that this is important for this problem, but here's the code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Group Name</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/united/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Group Name</h1>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Group Name</a>-->
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="contact.html">Contact List</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks! Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want retrieve all data on your Google Group,  you need to read the API Google Group.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/get_started
 You can use this on Javascript for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

he Groups Setting API Carter mentioned is for Group settings only, not member data.  To access Google Groups membership, you need to use the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list).

This link will show you how to make the API call to Google, from there you'll have to incorporate it into your webpage.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.